# Problemas al guardar una sesión en PHP (SESSION)

Tags: php, session

Estoy aprendiendo PHP y estoy programando un juego de hundir la flota con un sólo barco y cien casillas. El problema que estoy teniendo es que a la hora de solicitar al servidor el valor de la sesión que almacena el valor de la casilla en la que está el barco, no lo encuentra y no termino de encontrar la solución al problema por mucho que intento buscarla. Tengo tres ficheros:

- index.php: Es desde donde se "lanza" el misil para intentar adivinar la casilla del barco.
- trigger.php: Es desde donde se genera la cuadrícula y se asigna un valor de casilla al barco, almacenándolo dentro de una sesión.
- control.php: Es desde donde se procesa la respuesta del usuario, se lee el valor de la sesión del barco y las compara devolviendo el resultado.

Aquí los códigos de cada uno:

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Hundir La Flota</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="./control.php" method="post">
        ¿Dónde vas a golpear?&nbsp;<br/><input type='text' name='misil'>
        <input type='submit' value='Comprobar'>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**trigger.php**

```
<?php
    $cuadriculas = 100;
    $letras = array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J');

    function generarCuadricula($cuadriculas, $letras) {
        global $posiciones;
        $posiciones = array();
        $numActual = 1;
        $siguiente = 0;

        while(count($posiciones) < $cuadriculas){
            if($numActual == 11) {
                $numActual = 1;
                $siguiente += 1;
            };
            array_push($posiciones, $letras[$siguiente] . $numActual);
            $numActual++;
        };
    };

    function asignarCuadricula($posiciones) {
        session_start();
        $posBarco = $posiciones[rand(0, 99)];
        $_SESSION['barco'] = $posBarco;
    };

    generarCuadricula($cuadriculas, $letras);
    asignarCuadricula($posiciones);
?>
```

**control.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $posBarco = $_SESSION["barco"];
    $uHit = $_POST["misil"];

    function comprobarSiGolpe($uHit){
        echo "Has golpeado en: " . $uHit . "<br/>";
        echo "Posición barco: " . $posBarco . "<br/>";

        if($uHit == $_SESSION["barco"]){
            echo "¡Enhorabuena! Has hundido el barco." . "<br/>";
        } else {
            echo "Has fallado, vuelve a intentarlo." . "<br/>";
            echo '<a href="./index.php">Volver</a>';
        };
    };

    comprobarSiGolpe($uHit);
?>
```

Comment: Recuerda `session_start();` Solo debes utilizarlo una unica vez al inicio del documento  en un unico documento (el principal )

Comment: Pues acabo de reproducir tus scripts en mi servidor local y me funciona. Lo único raro es que primero debo ejecutar el trigger.php de forma separada, y luego el index.php para jugar, sino no va, porque en ningun momento ejecutas el trigger.php antes.

Comment: @masterguru Hola, es la intención, que primero haya que ejecutar trigger.php. En local a mí también me funciona pero uso otros dispositivos y no lo almacena. Por suerte, ya encontré una solución.

Comment: No se si te refieres a la respuesta que te he dado o bien otra cosa. Si lo que pretendes, por ejemplo, es ejecutar el trigger.php desde tu navegador y que los que visiten la página intenten adivinar la casilla entonces no te va a funcionar. La variable $_SESSION pertenece a la sesión actual de **tu** navegador, no de otros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A mi de este modo me funciona (abajo las explicaciones):

**index.php**

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    include("trigger.php");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Hundir La Flota</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="./control.php" method="post">
        ¿Dónde vas a golpear?&nbsp;<br/>
        <input type='text' name='misil'>
        <input type='submit' name="comprobar" value='Comprobar'>
        <input type='submit' name="empezar" value="Empezar de nuevo">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**trigger.php**

```
<?php
    // funciones
    function generarAsignarCuadricula($cuadriculas, $letras) {
        $posiciones = array();
        $numActual = 1;
        $siguiente = 0;

        while(count($posiciones) < $cuadriculas){
            if($numActual == 11) {
                $numActual = 1;
                $siguiente++;
            };
            array_push($posiciones, $letras[$siguiente] . $numActual);
            $numActual++;
        };

        // asignacion de cuadrícula
        $_SESSION['barco'] = $posiciones[rand(0, 99)];
    };

    // algoritmo //
    $cuadriculas = 100;
    $letras = array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J');

    // si no hay sesión no hacemos nada
    if (!isset($_SESSION['barco'])) {
        generarAsignarCuadricula($cuadriculas, $letras);
    }
?>
```

control.php

```
<?php
    // funciones
    function comprobarSiGolpe($uHit){
        $posBarco = $_SESSION["barco"];
        echo "Has golpeado en: " . $uHit . "<br/>";
        echo "Posición barco: " . $posBarco . "<br/>";

        if($uHit == $posBarco){
            echo "¡Enhorabuena! Has hundido el barco." . "<br/>";
        } else {
            echo "Has fallado, vuelve a intentarlo." . "<br/>";
            echo '<a href="./index.php">Volver</a>';
        };
    };

    // algoritmo //

    // Si hay que resetear destruimos la sesión y volvemos al inicio
    if (isset($_POST['empezar'])) {
        session_start();
        session_destroy();
        header('location:index.php');
        die();
    }

    // iniciamos sesión
    session_start();
    
    // validamos que el usuario no entra directamente en el script
    $uHit = $_POST["misil"] ?? die("algo salio mal!");
    
    // comprobamos si acierta o no
    comprobarSiGolpe($uHit);
?>
```

### Explicaciones:

**Cambios en el index.php**

1. En ningún momento llamabas a **trigger.php** forzando que fuera ejecutado de forma independiente antes de poder jugar con el **index.php** para que funcionara. Ahora lo he puesto en el index.php de este modo:

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    include("trigger.php");
?>
```

donde inicio una sesión que después será usada en el **trigger.php** (también se podría poner en el trigger.php, tanto da en este caso).

2. He creado un nuevo botón para resetear el juego y empezar de nuevo:

```
<input type='submit' name="empezar" value="Empezar de nuevo">
```

que será interpretado en el **control.php** para ello.

**Cambios en el trigger.php**

1. He reordenado algunas líneas pues me gusta separar las funciones del algoritmo, poniendo primero las funciones y luego la lógica del script
2. He juntado todo en una única función, pues tal como está no hace falta separarlo en dos. (a menos que luego lo necesites para otras cosas, en tal caso tu mismo lo vuelves a separar).
3. Como trigger.php siempre será invocado en el index.php, compruebo si ya tiene un valor o no en $_SESSION["barco"] para regenerar o no la cuadrícula y la asignación

**Cambios en control.php**

1. Igual que antes, he reordenado el script poniendo primero las funciones y luego su lógica
2. Compruebo si le han dado al nuevo botón **Empezar de nuevo**, y si se cumple elimino la sesión completamente con **session_destroy()** y regreso al index.php, donde, en este caso, cuando incluya el trigger.php, éste recalculará toda la cuadrícula y la asignación pues no tendrá definida la variable $_SESSION['barco'], volviendo a empezar el juego
3. En caso contrario, iniciamos la sesión, validamos si se recibe el dato $_POST['misil'], y en caso contrario paramos el script porque indica que ese archivo se ha abierto directamente, y no debemos hacer nada.

Verás otros cambios menores sin demasiada importancia, pero si no los entiendes pregunta.

Ya nos dirás si te ha funcionado y entendido.